# Zebra FX7500 - Problem connecting reader to MySQL database

Tags: http-post, rfid, zebra-printers, reader

I have an FX-7500 RFID Reader and my mission is to make an embedded system send the information of the tags read to a MySQL database that is in an internet domain. I have seen information that if I want to send data from the Reader to a database I must use the Java Embbebed SDK for Windows and in fact, I followed the manual that is there and I accomplished all those configuration steps that are there. However, I do not know how to configure the parameters of the MySQL database that I want to implement and since I have been like this for a month trying everything and well, it is a bit frustrating. I would like to know if you can give me clues or some templates to guide me since I know the language more or less and I have reviewed it in detail and I cannot find a way to find the objective.

I would really appreciate if you help me

Comment: It's not exactly clear what parameters you are looking for - parameters to put in your embedded application?

Another solution might be to use a RAIN RFID platform like Nedap Harmony (https://nedap-harmony.com) to get the data from the reader in a cloud-app and build from there.

Comment: The parameters which I trying to set-up are the page domain, the host, database name, database pass and the table where I gonna send the data tag captured by the reader. And the other provided solution its a good idea but the my final college project contempled just a direct http-post from the reader to the database without a cloud-app. If you can help me I would appreciate it.

Comment: Well...I'm thinking, do you know if its possible to post the data captured by the reader to a url of my domain, for example a php file?

Answer (score 2):

Using Zebra Data Services for RFID you can connect your FX Reader directly to Zebra's cloud (no middleware software or hardware).

From there you can assign a webhook (including tag filters and JQ data transformation). When event subscriptions are configured, read events occurring on the reader will be sent by the reader to the cloud. From there Zebra's cloud will forward that tag read event to your subscribed webhook.

Here is a link to the howto videos and data services available.

https://developer.zebra.com/apis/data-svcs-for-rfid

Comment: The problem in this solution is part of the challenge of my thesis is not use a cloud service as Zebra's Cloud to make possible the connection between the reader and my url domain and a the principal condition is use the JAVA Embedded SDK. In this way, I'm thinking a lot about this java document, do you know if it's possible to post the data captured by the reader to a certain url of my domain, for example a php file using this SDK and from this file send to my database?

Comment: Using a Java library it should be fairly straightforward to post a read event to a local LAN (or VPN connected) server hosting a REST endpoint. I am sure StackOverflow has plenty of suggestions on which Java libraries are best to use when making REST calls from inside your Java code base that is talking to the reader and querying it for tag read using LLRP.

Comment: In regards to writing to a data base. All of the major languages that have strong REST server libraries should also have libraries that can easily write to an MySQL DB. So whatever code you use to write your REST server should also have a library to simply writing (and reading) records in a MySQL db.